# Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.os.Parcelable[] cannot be cast to com.zhishi.o2o.model.ShortCut[]

Tags: android, casting, parcelable

```
shortCuts = (ShortCut[])getArguments().getParcelableArray("shortCut");
```

How can I  solve this problem?

Comment: does `com.zhishi.o2o.model.ShortCut` implement Parcelable?

Comment: have you implement parcelable interface in ShorCut class?

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement Parcelable to ShortCut class.

Like

```
public class ShortCut implement Parcelable{
//rest of code
}
```

I hope this will help you to understand.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem. My analog of the topicstarter's *ShortCut* class **definetely implements Parcelable**. The method in which I see this crash is executed very frequently - in `onViewCreated` of a ListFragment, but the crash happens very rare and isn't reproducible...